# How to merge code on GIT repo with the one on local machine?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am fairly new to using GIT. I am stuck in a problem while am working on a project. I will try to make the sequence simple to understand:

1 - A commits the code on GIT repo.

2 - A Makes some changes after commit. Does not commit them.

3 - B makes some changes and commits the code.

Now the thing is I am A and I don't want to lose the uncommitted changes that are on my local machine. Is there a way I can merge the project on GIT and the project on my local machine so that I don't lose any changes.
 Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

P.S: I am using GitHub Desktop app on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have 3 branches, branch A, branch B, branch develop or master (whatever)

You can do this:
In branch A: `git stash` -> this will save your uncommitted work

In branch B: commit and merge everything in the develop or master

In branch A: update your local repo with the remote, `git fetch` and then rebase your branch `git rebase -p origin/develop`

after rebase, in branch A, `git stash pop` -> this will put your code again

to learn more about git stash, read [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

if you are using the same branch but in different computers, do the same, but instead of fetch and rebase, just `git pull` and then `git stash pop`

Comment: Does this work: Do a local commit -> take pull (which acc to other answer will merge the changes).

Comment: Sounds good :) just be careful when you pull to do not lost any code..thats why I stash..  feels safer

Comment: Pls, if my answer helped you, accept it and give an upvote.. tkks